# Understanding how to derive Feynman Rules for the 2-point correlation function ($\phi^3$ theory)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, path-integral, perturbation-theory, interactions

This is a follow-up question ([first one here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/620562/)). I am aimed to work out $V(\phi) = -\lambda \frac{\phi^3}{3!}$ theory in detail to understand how Feynman rules can be derived from the functional integral

\begin{equation*}
Z[J] := \int d[\phi] e^{iS[\phi] + i\int d^d x J(x) \phi(x)} \tag{1}
\end{equation*}

I performed a completely analogous computation to that of Jeanbaptiste Roux, up to second order in perturbation theory, and obtained

\begin{align*}
    &\exp\left(\frac{i}{2}\int d^d x \int d^d y \frac{\delta}{\delta \phi(x)}\Delta_F(x-y) \frac{\delta}{\delta \phi(y)}\right)\times \exp\left(i \int d^d z \left( -\frac{\lambda}{3!}\phi^3+J\phi \right)\right)\Big|_{\phi=0}  \\
    &=1+\frac{i}{2}\times 0+\frac{i}{2}\int d^d x \int d^d y\,(i(J(x))\Delta_F(x-y)(iJ(y)) \\
    &+ \frac{(i)^2}{4}\int d^d x \int d^d y \int d^d t \int d^d \xi\,(iJ(x))\Delta_F(x-y)(iJ(y)) (iJ(t))\Delta_F(t-\xi)(iJ(\xi)) + \mathcal{O}(\Delta_F^3)
\end{align*}

So it seems to me that the perturbative expansion is determined by the number of propagators!

So, up to first order, we encounter one propagator and $2$ external legs $iJ$

Up to second order we encounter two propagators and $4$ external legs $iJ$

I've just learned that the source $J$ is represented by a vertex with one outgoing line i.e.

[image]

With this information, I was trying to understand why, for instance, the 2-point correlation function $\langle \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) \rangle$ has the following contributions up to second order

[image]

Why should we draw a bubble like shown above? If I am not mistaken, we should have two external legs due to having two propagators and $4$ vertices due to having $4$ sources. However, I only see two vertices here... what am I missing?

PS: Please note this is not a homework question. I am studying  [Osborn notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/ho/), [section 2.2. Interacting Scalar Field Theories](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/ho/AQFTNotes.pdf), and I want to understand how he constructed the Feynman rules (page 23) via working out the simplest example I could find: $\phi^3$ theory

**EDIT 0**

Let me go slowly here. I will only focus on second order terms. As stated in the comments, we should get $\propto \int \mathrm{d}^4 z \int \mathrm{d}^4 w J(x) \Delta_F(x-z) \Delta_F^2(z-w) \Delta_F(w-y) J(y)$

This is what I have done so far

\begin{align*}
&\exp\left(\frac{i}{2}\int d^d x \int d^d y \frac{\delta}{\delta \phi(x)}\Delta_F(x-y) \frac{\delta}{\delta \phi(y)}\right) \exp\left(i \int d^d t \left( -\frac{\lambda}{3!}\phi^3+J\phi \right)\right)\Big|_{\phi=0}
\\
&=\left[\cdots +\frac{(i)^2}{4}\int d^{2d} z \int d^{2d} w \left(\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi(z)}\right)^2\Delta_F^2(z-w) \left(\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi(w)}\right)^2+\cdots \right]\left.e^{i \int d^d t \left( -\frac{\lambda}{3!}\phi^3+J\phi \right)}\right|_{\phi=0}
\\
&=\left[1+\frac{(i)^2}{4}\int d^{2d} z\int d^{2d} w \left(\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi(z)}\right)^2\Delta_F^2(z-w)\left(\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi(w)}\right)\left( -\frac{\lambda}{2}i\phi^2(w)+iJ(w)\right) +\cdots\right] \\
&\times \left.e^{i \int d^d t \left( -\frac{\lambda}{3!}\phi^3+J\phi \right)}\right|_{\phi=0}
\end{align*}

Is this OK so far?

Comment: x, z, w, y are the 4 vertices...

Comment: @NiharKarve Oh, I misunderstood the word vertex then! Let me ask a naïve question: Why do we get a loop though? I mean, I have been told that once we go to second order and above we expect to encounter loops, but why?

Comment: OK my computation up to second order in perturbation theory is wrong. I will check it and add my second attempt

Comment: In the expansion you have written down, you have kept only the terms or order $\lambda^0$. This reproduces the free theory; $n$-point correlators are obtained from $Z[J]$ by differentiating $n$-times with respect to $J$ and then setting $J=0$. If you want the interaction effect you have to look for terms of order $\lambda$. The loops arise since in the interaction you have terms like $\phi(x)^3$.

Comment: I've done the calculations. If I am right you should come with four tadpoles and a "double propagator" (two non-intersecting lines).

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux I thank you, I indeed strongly suspect that the answer should be $\propto \int \mathrm{d}^4 z \int \mathrm{d}^4 w J(x) \Delta_F(x-z) \Delta_F^2(z-w) \Delta_F(w-y) J(y)$  i.e. only two $iJ$. I will soon post an edit to show where I am stuck

Comment: Ah, I've done the calculations for the $\Delta_F (x-y) \Delta_F(z-\xi)$ term appearing in the expansion of the exponential of the functional differential operators, so not the right one... But yes given the form of the loop you seek, it should be something like you said.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux This is what I've done so far (please see edit 0). Are we on the same page? Should I simply proceed by performing the functional derivatives?

Comment: You can't do what you've done because the square of an integral is not the double integral of the square of the integrand: $\left[\int dx f(x) \right]^2=\int dx f(x) \int dy f(y) \neq \int d^{2x} f^2(x)$.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux I see, so just to be crystal clear: in the first equality of edit 0 we should deal with $\frac{(i)^2}{4}\int d x \int d y \left(\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi(x)}\right)\Delta_F(x-y) \left(\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi(y)}\right)\int d z \int d w \left(\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi(z)}\right)\Delta_F(z-w) \left(\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi(w)}\right)$ instead, shouldn't we?

Comment: If this is the calculation you want, the one I've done, you should find something like $-\lambda \int d^d z d^d w \Delta(0) \Delta(z-w)J(z)+\frac{1}{4}\int d^d x \int d^d y \int d^d z \int d^d w \Delta(x-y) \Delta(z-w) J(x) J(y) J(z) J(w)$. If you want the loop you encircled, this is not the right calculation: to have four $\Delta$s you have to deal with the fourth term of the expansion (if "$1$" is called the zeroth).

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux oh I am a bit confused then. Might you please share your computation, posting an answer? I am struggling to see how to deal with several derivatives in this context

Comment: I will, in under 1 hour it will be done.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux Thank you. I will add an edit 1 regarding how many propagators should we expect regarding each order of perturbation theory before performing the computation.

Comment: Well, I think I better post another question to discuss that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, like it can be seen in the comments, I will perform the calculations for the second term of the expansion of the exponential containing the functional derivatives. I will denote $\phi(x)$ by $\phi_x$ and $\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi(x)}$ by $\delta_{\phi_x}$.
\begin{align*}
&-\frac{1}{4}\int d^d x \int d^d y \int d^d z \int d^d w \Delta_F(x-y) \Delta_F(z-w)\delta_{\phi_x}\delta_{\phi_y}\delta_{\phi_z}\delta_{\phi_w}\left.e^{i \int d^d \xi(-\frac{\lambda}{3!}\phi^3+J\phi)}\right|_{\phi=0}
\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}\int d^d x \int d^d y \int d^d z \int d^d w \Delta_F(x-y) \Delta_F(z-w)\delta_{\phi_x}\delta_{\phi_y}\delta_{\phi_z}\left[i\left( -\frac{\lambda}{2}\phi^2_w+J_w \right)  \right]
\\
&\hphantom{==}\times\left.e^{i \int d^d \xi(-\frac{\lambda}{3!}\phi^3+J\phi)}\right|_{\phi=0}
\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}\int d^d x \int d^d y \int d^d z \int d^d w \Delta_F(x-y) \Delta_F(z-w)\delta_{\phi_x}\delta_{\phi_y}\left[\vphantom{\frac{1}{2}}i\left( -\lambda \phi_w \delta_{w,z} \right)  \right.
\\
&\hphantom{==}\left. - \left(-\frac{\lambda}{2} \phi^2_w +J_w \right)\left( -\frac{\lambda}{2} \phi^2_z +J_z  \right) \right]\left.e^{i \int d^d \xi(-\frac{\lambda}{3!}\phi^3+J\phi)}\right|_{\phi=0}
\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}\int d^d x \int d^d y \int d^d z \int d^d w \Delta_F(x-y) \Delta_F(z-w)\delta_{\phi_x}\left[\vphantom{\frac{1}{2}} -i\lambda \delta_{w,y}\delta_{w,z}-\left( -\lambda \phi_w \delta_{w,y} \right) \right.
\\
&\hphantom{==}\left.\times\left( -\frac{\lambda}{2}\phi^2_z+J_z \right)-\left( -\frac{\lambda}{2}\phi^2_w+J_w \right) \left( -\lambda \phi_z \delta_{zy} \right)+\left[-i\lambda \phi_w \delta_{w,z}-\left( -\frac{\lambda}{2}\phi^2_w+J_w\right)\right.\right.
\\
&\hphantom{==}\left.\left.\times \left(-\frac{\lambda}{2}\phi^2_z+J_z\right)\right]\left( -i\frac{\lambda}{2}\phi^2_y+iJ_y\right)\right]\left.e^{i \int d^d \xi(-\frac{\lambda}{3!}\phi^3+J\phi)}\right|_{\phi=0}
\end{align*}
From here we just have to see that only the terms having zero $\phi$ in them after the ultimate derivation will survive to the limit $\phi \rightarrow 0$. So using one last time $(uv)'=u'v+uv'$ we arrive at the conclusion that the result ought to be:
\begin{align*}
&-\frac{1}{4}\int d^d x \int d^d y \int d^d z \int d^d w \Delta_F(x-y) \Delta_F(z-w)\left[\lambda \delta_{w,x}\delta_{w,y}J_z \right.
\\
&\hphantom{==}+\lambda\delta_{z,y}\delta_{z,x}J_w+\lambda\delta_{w,x}\delta_{w,z}J_y+\lambda \delta_{w,y}\delta_{w,z}J_x+J_x J_y J_z J_w]
\end{align*}
We see that the integrand is composed of four tadpoles and one double propagator (two non-intersecting lines). Equating the terms that are equal to each other one finds:
\begin{align*}
&-\lambda \int d^d z \int d^d w \Delta_F (0) \Delta_F (z-w)
\\
&-\frac{1}{4}\int d^d x \int d^d y \int d^d z \int d^d w \Delta_F(x-y) \Delta_F(z-w) J_x J_y J_z J_w
\end{align*}
I didn't check my calculations, hope there is no sign problem.